# matrix elements of $\hat{z}$ operator under the angular momentum basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, spherical-harmonics

I found a quite challenge quantum mechanics problem in a preparation sample test for a midterm. The sample test does not have a solution, so it is bothering.

The question reads as follows:

> Consider an electron moving in a central potential. Suppose that we know the matrix element of the $z$-position operator between two states:
>   $$\langle j',m'|\,z\,|j,m\rangle
> $$
>   (i) Justify that $m'=m$ for this matrix element to be non-zero;
>
> (ii) What are the constraints on $j$ and $j'$ for non-zero matrix elements?
>
> (iii) Given a none-zero matrix element $\langle j',m'|\,z\,|j,m\rangle$  (with $m=m'$ and suitable constraints on $j'$ and $j$), give a general formula to compute the matrix elements:
>   $$\langle j',m'''|\,x\,|j,m''\rangle
> $$

I am stuck at the (i) question. I tried to use algebraic methods but it seemed useless. By algebraic methods, I mean inserting $J_z$ and noticing $[J_z,z]=0$, but this only gives a relation of $m$. Then I tried to use spherical harmonic wavefunction $Y_m^j$. However, if $\hat{z}=\hat{r}\cos(\hat{\theta})$, then one will eventually compute the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}P^m_j(x)P^{m'}_{j'}(x)xdx
$$
where we have $P_j^m(-x)=(-1)^{(m+j)}P_j^m(x)$. Hence, (i) statement may not be true.

Can someone give me a hint or some detailed calculation? Appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: There is a useful recursion formula, 
$$(2l+1)xP^m_l(x) = (l + m)P^m_{l-1}(x)+(l-m+1)P^m_{l+1}(x).$$

But this is a bit... awkward. I can't see how someone could see this through on an exam.

There is another way (which may be better), where one can exploit the relationships between the commutators of $L_z$. In fact, you've already done that, but it seems you've missed something, so maybe go back and check your work again.

Comment: Does this mean that the statement $(i)$ is not true in general? According to the recursion formula, the integral is non-vanishing if $j$ and $j'$ deviate 1.

Comment: Sorry, what does "deviate 1" mean?

Comment: I mean when $|j-j'|=1$

Comment: Ah, I think part (ii) handles your question

Comment: No, the $(ii)$ assumes that $m\neq m'$, so they are different.

Comment: Where does (ii) state that $m' \neq m$? Contrary, it would make sense if it was a follow up to part (i), in which case $\langle z\rangle \neq 0 \rightarrow m' = m,$ from part (i)

Comment: (i) assume $m=m'$, then ask to prove the formula is not zero for any $j$ and $j'$. (ii) Now, to get $non-zero$ term, assuming (i)'s results, we now need to investigate the case where $m\neq m'$. I think this is what the problem asks.

Comment: Oh, I think you've got it backward. It says: Justify $m' = m$ [...], which means that is the statement you must prove, not assume.

Comment: Oh, that would be a good hint. Language always mess up problems. I will try to doublecheck the gramma. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Please feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: Yes, I would say the logic is more comprehensive. Thanks Zhang.

Comment: Hi Zhang, I also have some question about part (ii). As you said, it is not easy for someone figure out the above relation of Legendre polynomial during an exam, and I also checked the formula is not on the help sheet. Do you have any idea about the algebraic way? Appreciated. Otherwise, I may re-start a new question.